# Spring cloud not able to resolve vault secret into .yml

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, hashicorp-vault, spring-vault

I'm working with microservice architecture and have spring cloud config service and another microservice.

```
  profiles:
    active: vault
  cloud:
    # Configuration for a vault server running in dev mode
    vault:
      scheme: http
      host: 127.0.0.1
      port: 8200
      connection-timeout: 5000
      read-timeout: 15000
      authentication: TOKEN
      token: s.E4gdoIYAKxMvCE56MP5Etmvy
      kv:
        enabled: true
        backend: secret
        backend-version: 2
        profile-separator: /
      generic:
          enabled: false
      application-name: myapp
```

Config server dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-vault-config</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

this is into .yml into the config service. Then into the .yml for my microservice i have db.username property which I want to resolve from Vault but I can't. Do you have any ideas?

```
username: db.username
password: secret/apm-transaction-service/dev/db.user

@Value("${db.username}")
```

this value is resolved into the java code but not into the .yml

Now for each microservice which I have I want to resolve the secrets from the configuration service without making any changes into the microservices. Currently reading native .ymls from the config service and want to add one more source :)

ApplicationStartupRunner run method Started !!root

Comment: what is your config server configuration?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Are you running spring cloud config server?

Comment: yes -> spring cloud config server

Comment: Please show the configuration of your config server

Answer (score 0):

if you are using spring-boot, for the value in .yml file to be resolved it has to be a variable. you must use ${db.username} in the yaml file

Comment: ${db.username} will resolve this placeholder if the vault configuration is into the microservice, but I want the microservice do not have any vault configurations and all configs to be into the config service. Then ${db.username} is not resolvable into microservice.yml file

Comment: the spring cloud config server provides rest endpoints to get properties. if you use spring cloud config client, the properties are resolved as if they were provided to the propertyplaceholder